# Error Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder" Apache Kafka

Tags: java, gradle, slf4j

I'm facing the error Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder" when i build the Java class and run. I'm following the lessons of book "Apache Kafka Quick Start Guide". The Java project is compiled as gradle project. I already include 'slf4j-simple' in the build.gradle file, but the error persist.

I'm typing `gradle jar` to build .jar file.

The error:

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for 
further details.
```

And the build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'

sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

mainClassName = 'monedero.ProcessingEngine'

repositories {
   mavenCentral()
}

version = '0.1.0'

dependencies {
   compile group: 'org.apache.kafka', name: 'kafka_2.12', version: 
   '2.0.0'
   compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-core', 
   version: '2.9.7'
   testCompile group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-simple', version:  
   1.6.1'
             }

jar {
    manifest {
       attributes 'Main-Class': mainClassName
    } from {
       configurations.compile.collect {
          it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it)
    }
}
exclude "META-INF/*.SF"
exclude "META-INF/*.DSA"
exclude "META-INF/*.RSA"
}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with Kafka and isn't an error. Read the link provided

Comment: Hi! I  have already opened the link and i have read others similar questions in stackoverflow, but not work for me.

Comment: That's not an error, just an obnoxious log message. Your program will still run, you just won't get log output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to change `testCompile` to just `compile` for those classes to be loaded by the main application.

Comment: i going to try now!

Comment: `simple` is an actual log implementation.